# Can this be made prettier? Matching string to case class field

Tags: scala

Sorry about the title, please edit it to be more descriptive if you can!

Is there a way to generalize this with scala? I have quite a few fields that can be filtered against, and this is just plain ugly! The problem I ran against was matching parameter name against the case class field, can it be done in a more general way, without this much code duplication?

```
get("/MostClicked") { request =>
  val res = MongoDbOps.findMostClicked()
  val res1 = request.params.get("source") match {
    case None => res
    case Some(f) => res.filter(_.source == f)
  }
  val res2 = request.params.get("category") match {
    case None => res1
    case Some(f) => res1.filter(_.category == f)
  }
  // more of the same...

  render.plain {
    res2.toJson.prettyPrint
  }.toFuture
}
```

Comment: What is the point of `res1`? You probably wanted `res1.filter` in `res2` assignment?

Comment: @EndeNeu you are correct, fixed

Comment: Since you want to apply two filters to the same data, you could `compose` the two filters first. Hence, you wouldn't have `res1`, but `res` in the second match, making the two code snippets more similar. I still don't know how to get rid of the distinction of `.source` and `.category` though. I'm just thinking: "If the two matches were the same, you could extract them"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try either of the two approaches below.

```
  case class MostClicked(
    source: String,
    category: String,
    rating: String)

  object MongoDbOps {
    def findMostClicked() = List[MostClicked]()
  }

  class Request {
    val params = Map[String, String]()
  }

  def get(path: String)(f: Request => String) = {
    f(new Request)
  }
```

First is to use a List of matchers and then apply them sequentially using `foldLeft`:

```
  get("/MostClicked") { request =>
    val res = MongoDbOps.findMostClicked()

    val kfun = List(
      "source" -> ((x: MostClicked, y: String) => x.source == y),
      "category" -> ((x: MostClicked, y: String) => x.category == y),
      "rating" -> ((x: MostClicked, y: String) => x.rating == y))

    val r = kfun.foldLeft(res) { (x, y) =>
      request.params.get(y._1)
        .map(f => res.filter(y._2(_, f)))
        .getOrElse(x)
    }

    r.toString

    // more of the same...

    render.plain {
      r.toJson.prettyPrint
    }.toFuture

  }
```

Or simply make it more readable:

```
  get("/MostClicked") { request =>
    val res = MongoDbOps.findMostClicked()

    val res1 = request.params.get("source")
      .map(f => res.filter(_.source == f))
      .getOrElse(res)

    val res2 = request.params.get("category")
      .map(f => res.filter(_.category == f))
      .getOrElse(res1)

    val res3 = request.params.get("rating")
      .map(f => res.filter(_.rating == f))
      .getOrElse(res2)

    // more of the same...

    render.plain {
      res3.toJson.prettyPrint
    }.toFuture

  }
```

Comment: You can make type check more accurate by making matcher function generic. From your example, it seems all the values are of type `String`.

Answer (score 2):

I had to break it down to parts and work out the types, thus the smaller methods.
It works in my simple experiment and gets rid of the duplication where it can, but might not be as readable?

Note that unless you get into reflection, you still need to create the name of the parameter and how it should be filtered.

This looks to be the same as tuxdna's answer except with types to increase readability and maintainability

**SETUP**

```
case class Request(params: Map[String, String])
case class Result(category: String, source: String)
type Filterer = (Result, String) => Boolean
case class FilterInfo(paramName: String, filterer: Filterer)
type Analyzer = FilterInfo => List[Result]
val request = Request(Map("source"->"b"))
```

**EXTRACTION METHODS**

```
def reduce(filterInfos: List[FilterInfo], results: List[Result]) = {
  filterInfos.foldLeft(results) { (currentResult, filterInfo) =>
    request.params.get(filterInfo.paramName)
      .map(filterVal => currentResult.filter(filterInfo.filterer(_, filterVal)))
      .getOrElse(currentResult)
  }
}
```

**USAGE**

```
val filterInfos = List(
              FilterInfo("source", (result, filterVal) => result.source == filterVal), 
              FilterInfo("category", (result, filterVal) => result.category == filterVal))
val res = List(Result("a","a"), Result("b", "b"))

reduce(filterInfos, res)
```

**Used in your example it would be more like this:**

```
get("/MostClicked") { request =>
  val res = MongoDbOps.findMostClicked()
  val filterInfos = List(
              FilterInfo("source", (result, filterVal) => result.source == filterVal), 
              FilterInfo("category", (result, filterVal) => result.category == filterVal))  
  val finalResult = reduce(filterInfos, res)

  render.plain {
    finalResult.toJson.prettyPrint
  }.toFuture
}
```